# Not getting Ether on contract wallet

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

on my Ethereum wallet I've created a contract based wallet (as it was recommended in guides to see details about all my transactions) and I was useing this wallet as my main pay address. Everything was OK untill april 13. After this day my wallet stoped to recive any transactions, it seems like all Ethereum that was send to my contract based wallet just disappeared, cause multiple transactions were made from different services on this address, but I didn't get any of them.

Then I tried to make a transaction on my base wallet and it worked.

So I can't get what's wrong. What may be the problem?

Sry for bad englando.

Comment: There is no such thing as `disappeared` in Ethereum Blockchain, it is prevented by design. Could you please post the source code of the contract to investigate further.

Comment: Please post the address of the account / wallet. If you haven't done so, you need to use etherscan to look at the balance and transactions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what data you want from me. But here's something that can probably help:

Transaction hash: https://etherchain.org/tx/0x9ee381009224c53c6461b13d168f00b8ab14d067ccd443d03c4647e0e654f9d5

0.25 ETH were send to my wallet, but I didn't recive any transactions after april 13

Here the screenshot of my wallet: http://i.imgur.com/k02BYf5.png

Comment: And also - on etherchain.org I went to transactions section and here was all transactions (even that I didn't recive still) and  etherchain.org says balans of my wallet is 3.5 ETH (that actually is), but sum of all transactions showed on  etherchain.org is about 4 ETH (that should be with all the transactions I didn't recive).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not seeing them in Ethereum Wallet, typically it means 1 of 2 things: either your Ethereum Wallet is not syncing with the blockchain or your contract isn't receiving the ETH for some reason. So, let's take a look at EtherScan (a blockchain explorer) to see if we can determine what is going on:

Your address is [0x0b70d28e07a0913afb865c9575dadaf45f62ea4a](http://etherscan.io/address/0x0b70d28e07a0913afb865c9575dadaf45f62ea4a).

The balance is 3.5ETH, with the last transaction of .108ETH occurring ~11 hours ago.

Unfortunately, the last 3 transactions have: `Warning! An error occurred during contract execution. Out Of Gas?`. This is indicated by the red asterisk next to the TxHash. If you click the transaction hash on EtherScan you can see the error message.

You need to include more gas with your transaction moving forward.

In the future, please always include the address all accounts/transactions so that people can look and see what is going on and better help you.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I still don't get what exactly should I do. Do you mean, that the service which send me ETH didn't use enough gas so I didn't recive the transaction? Or the problem on my side? What should I do then? And can I recive this transactions that was lost?

Comment: Yes, whatever is sending you the ETH is not using enough gas. The standard transaction costs 21000. To send to a contract, it needs more depending on the amount of data, etc. If you are sending from an exchange or something else, you should NOT send to a contract address until the exchanges update and allow you to alter the amount of gas provided. Send to a normal account and then, if you want, send to your contract.

Comment: Oh got it now, thx. And where the money gone then? Did it return to the sender? Of just gone?

Comment: The whole transaction is canceled and the entire amount is sent back to the original user and the function of the contract are never run. So, the person who sent you those ETH should have them.

Comment: Thx once again, gonna ask the service to repeat transactions then.